# How to create an adhoc 3 node Gigabit Ethernet network at "Home", file transfer for NAS?

Tags: networking, nas, ethernet, ad-hoc-network

I have 3 devices that are Gigabit Ethernet:

- Windows XP PRO PC
- D-Link DSM-G600 NAS
- Intel SS4200E - NAS

My goal is to quickly transfer the 457GB of data on the D-Link DSM-G600 NAS to the Intel SS4200E – NAS.  The problem is my current switch and router are 10/100 Mbps and I am seeing file copy speeds between 5 MB/s and 8 MB/s. This may be handicapped by the fact that I am using windows to initiate the transfer.

I would like to speed this up by upgrading something.  But, if I can go cheap and do an adhoc set up just for the initial transfer between the D-Link DSM-G600 NAS to the Intel SS4200E – NAS  that would be great.

Would getting just a new switch like a [D-Link DGS-2208 10/100/1000Mbps 8-Port Desktop Green Ethernet Switch 8 x RJ45 8K MAC Address Table 144KB per Device Packet Buffer Memory Buffer Memory](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833127082) help?  If so, how would I set it up, just to complete this task?

Other suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is Windows used to start is not really a Windows issue - Whatever OS you chose, it will always go *via* that machine.

What I would recommend you did was use something like Rsync (if possible) or if you have shell access, do a direct copy from one NAS to Another.

You can easily transfer files directly if you have a crossover network cable and manually assign the IP addresses.

That being said, I would personally get that switch! it seems to be a very good price and it would solve the problem of changing the IP's back when you are done (if these are headless NASs), and it is just better if you are going to be doing large file transfers in the future.

Comment: No need for cross-over cable with gigabit ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a GBps switch.  The speed you are being shown is Mega-bytes per second while the connection n is Mega-bits per second.  If you take 100Mbps/8 (to get bytes) you will get 12.5MBps.  Then you need to take into account that about 40% of the traffic is lost to network contention and protocol overhead leaving you with about 7.5MBps of useable bandwidth.  If you get a gig-switch you should be able to get a max of 75MBps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the switch. Setup is easy, just plug in all your machines and enjoy :)

The alternative is putting an extra gigabit lan card in your xp machine and getting 2 cross-over lan cables and connecting the NAS machines to your XP machine and initiating the transfer.